# Does a subclass of a custom fragment call the saveInstanceState method of its super class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, superclass

So I have a class that extends fragment

```
public class General_Fragment extends Fragment{

    int i;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(INTEGER_KEY, getInt());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public int getInt(){
        return i;
    }

    …
}
```

And another class that extends this first class.

```
public class Specific_Fragment extends General_Fragment{
    int j;

    @Override
    public int getInt(){
        return j;
    }

    …
}
```

When the Specific Fragment is destroyed the General_Fragments onSavedInstanceState should be called correct? Or do I need to implement something in the subclass to call the superclass method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not override the `onSaveInstanceState` method in `Specific_Fragment`, the one implemented in `General_Fragment` will be called.

So there's no need to override it, as long as you don't need to save something else that from the most derived fragment.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to override it to be called, it's inherited from its parent class which is `General_Fragment`